# Mcrypt PHP extension required on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, laravel, laravel-4, mamp, mcrypt

I keep getting this error

> **Mcrypt PHP extension required**

at the bottom after I run a `composer update` :

[image]

Since I am using Mac, I have tried running :

`brew search mcrypt
brew install php56-mcrypt`

I still get the same error message.

Comment: Sure that the mcrypt extension is not already installed, but only not activated yet in the php configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure if the installation went through because I still get the error "Mcrypt PHP extension required." in the bottom after running composer update.

Comment: Well, look into the place in your file system where the extensions are installed...

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Steps

I solved this by running the following commands

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php54-mcrypt
php --version // To Test your php 
sudo composer update
```

---

## Result

No more Mcrypt warning !!

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

Comment: `brew install homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt` will do too

Comment: Yeah as @BingHan said it will do it, just pick the good php version and your are good!

Comment: Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated. Please update your answer.

Comment: brew tap homebrew/dupes
Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Answer (score 14):

After update brew:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
```

If you have installed php5.6 (or higher), you can use the following command to find out what versions are available in brew:

```
$ brew search mcrypt
homebrew/php/php53-mcrypt     homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt         homebrew/php/php70-mcrypt     mcrypt
homebrew/php/php54-mcrypt     homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt     homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt
```

In my case, I am using php7.0:

```
$ brew install php70-mcrypt
```

Comment: brew search mcrypt is important because it will most likely return what you need. In my case (I assume they have consolidated the versioning) I got "libtomcrypt", "mcrypt", "scrypt", "ccrypt", and "bycrypt" on my search results. I then just ran brew install mcrypt and all was resolved. So great answer @CharlieJade

Answer (score 7):

On **macOS High Sierra** I did this steps:

1- Search the package:

```
brew search mcrypt
```

Result:

> ==> Searching local taps... homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt                  mcrypt                                    homebrew/php/php53-mcrypt
>   homebrew/php/php54-mcrypt                   homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt 
>   homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt                   homebrew/php/php70-mcrypt 
>   libtomcrypt

2- Search my php version to know what can I need to install:

```
php --version
```

Result:

> PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017
>   Zend Technologies

3- Install the correct package, for me was 7.1.7 => homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt

```
brew install homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt
```

4- Find the find "mcrypt.so" extension file

```
find /usr/ -type f -name "mcrypt.so"
```

Result:

> find: 
>   /usr//local/Cellar/php71-mcrypt/7.1.13_19/mcrypt.so

5- Search the php.ini

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

Result (if exist):

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc Loaded Configuration File =>
>   /etc/php.ini

6- Add the next line at the end on /etc/php.ini (see the last step your correct path) the extension mcrypt.so

```
 extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php71-mcrypt/7.1.13_19/mcrypt.so
```

Finish, you can now execute your command.

Comment: I am using XAMPP, it is not working here. Any other way?

Comment: Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Comment: I like watching this step.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to add the line

```
 extension=mcrypt.so
```

In your phi.ini file responsible for the CLI PHP version.
To find where it is, run:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

Comment: I already have it in my `php.ini` I checked it. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: When I run `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'` I see this : 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => (none)

Comment: Try this: run `find /usr/lib/php/extensions -type f -name "mcrypt.so"` this should give you the path where the extension is located. Then, add the directive `extension_dir=/usr/lib/php./....../mcrypt.so` before the `extension=mcrypt.so` of your php.ini

Comment: When I run `find /usr/lib/php/extensions -type f -name "mcrypt.so"` I don't have anything as my outcomes.

Comment: @ihue did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

In use **XAMPP** on my Mac, so I had to install php and then compile mcrypt using pecl, after that I copied mcrypt.so to XAMPP.

The actual list of available releases is: http://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt

The commands was:

```
echo Install php...
brew install php
/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php -v

echo Correction of "error Connection to `ssl://pecl.php.net:443' failed"...
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
sudo cp cacert.pem /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem
sudo mv cacert.pem /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem
/usr/local/opt/php/bin/pecl list-all

echo Compile and Install mcrypt.so...
sudo /usr/local/opt/php/bin/pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

The last message of build process of **pecl** was:

> ```
> Build process completed successfully
> Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.7/pecl/20170718/mcrypt.so'
> install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mcrypt-1.0.1
> Extension mcrypt enabled in php.ini
> ```

Based on path of **build process** I copied the compiled mcrypt.so to XAMPP and enable the extension on php.ini:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.7/pecl/20170718/mcrypt.so /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mcrypt.so 
echo 'extension=mcrypt.so' >> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
```

Check if it works:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php -i | grep "mcrypt"
```

The result have to be:

> ```
> mcrypt
> mcrypt support => enabled
> mcrypt_filter support => enabled
> mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
> mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
> ```

Remember to **restart Apache** to see it working using browser.

Maybe it helps someone and I win one **thumbs up**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you using **brew** try this :

1.**Unistall existing php** then Install shivammathur/php

add shivammathur php

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
```

change php version with you needed (5.6 or 7.2 or 7.4 or 8.1 or next version)

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.1
```

2.Install shivammathur/extensions it s will add extension to php
then

```
brew tap shivammathur/extensions

brew install shivammathur/extensions/mcrypt@8.1
```

then you install mcrypt with same version as php version

```
brew install mcrypt@8.1
```

then restart httpd

```
brew services restart httpd
```

Ref :

https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions