# Magento composer installation

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to install magento but I have a problem when I call the composer to install it. With the command 'composer install' I receive this two problems:

```
  Problem 1
- The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mcrypt extension.
  Problem 2
- The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
```

I read in the site and I find a solution related to the command 'sudo apt-get...' and also in this case, shell gives me an error saying that the command cannot be find. I saw around on internet and, sincerely, I don't understand some of the solution I read around. Are you able to explain to me how can I solve it? I will appreciate your help!

Comment: you need to install `mcrypt`. how? that's depends about your environment.

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows, or even Mac?

Comment: I'm with a Mac @Mikkel

Comment: @Federkun I understand it. That's why I'm here. Maybe some of you are able to help me

Comment: On the Mac, you can use homebrew (apt-get is for linux). Read about it here http://brew.sh/

Comment: @Mikkel, just to be sure, I have to install it and then I should try again to use the command "composer install", is it right?

Comment: I'm not an expert on php, but this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329999/mcrypt-php-extension-required-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @Mikkel, update, it is "blocked" at 'downloading command line tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode'. As my wi fi is slow, can you give me a feedback if I'm doing right or not?

Comment: It does take a while to set up, installing packages from there is usually pretty fast

Comment: @Mikkel okay, I will try those steps you send me when the download will end its work. Thank you

Comment: @Mikkel it's almost 15 minutes I wait for it. I think it is for the worst wifi ever